# Most efficient Object-Oriented approach to a 4-way temperature converter

Tags: c#, oop

So, I'm trying to work on a Temperature Converter that will convert any Fahrenheit, Celsius, Kelvin or Rankine source temperature to Fahrenheit, Celsius, Kelvin or Rankine.

Now, I'm trying to do this (in C#) following the guidelines of best OO practices.

I've hit a roadblock early on though, and I need some advice on how to continue.

I have a class, `TempConvert`, currently handling the interface and implementation of the program.

Then, I have a `Main.cs` file which will actually carry out the `Main()` method.

This will be a console program, mind you.

**TempConvert.cs**

```
using System;

namespace TempConverter
{
    public class TempConvert
    {
        private double SourceTemp { get; set; }
        private double TargetTemp { get; set; }

        public TempConvert(double sourceTemp, double targetTemp)
        {
            SourceTemp = sourceTemp;
            TargetTemp = targetTemp;
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.cs**

```
using System;

namespace TempConverter
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            TempConvert converter = new TempConvert(10, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I don't know if this is a good start or not.

I can't think of how to handle for different Source Temperatures (via the 4 different scale I'm accounting for) and the different Target Temperatures.

My above code cannot work, at least I think, because as I pass `10` as a `SourceTemp` value, and `20` as a `TargetTemp` value, there is no way to determine which scale the end-user desires.

Perhaps, I could pass a third parameter, an `int`, which contains a value 1, 2, 3 or 4.  Then, using a conditional, a certain conversion method is invoked, because each integer will correspond to a certain scale.

Answer (score 3):

You want something like this:

```
interface ITemperatureConverter {
    double Convert(double temperature);
}

class FahrenheitToCelciusConverter : ITemperatureConverter {
    // details elided
}
```

> Perhaps, I could pass a third parameter, an int, which contains a value 1, 2, 3 or 4. Then, using a conditional, a certain conversion method is invoked, because each integer will correspond to a certain scale.

You can take this farther and say:

```
enum TemperatureScale { Celcius, Fahrenheit, Kelvin, Rankine };

class TemperatureConverterFactory {
    // details elided

    public ITemperatureConverter CreateConverter(
        TemperatureScale from,
        TemperatureScale to
    ) {
        // details elided
    }
}
```

You need to have the `CreateConverter` method return the appropriate `ITemperatureConverter`.

Edited to respond to your questions:

> Thanks for the response, but could you explain this a little more from a n00by perspective? I'm having some trouble interpreting your second block of code.

A key principle in OOP is the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). One manifestation of the single-responsibility principle is that every class should have and only one responsibility.

A particular piece of responsibility in the program that you are building is performing a temperature conversion. That is the point of the interface `ITemperatureConverter` and the concrete implementations such as `FahrenheitToCelciusConverter`. Note that `FahrenheitToCelciusConverter` ONLY converts Fahrenheit to Celsius. That is its single responsibility.

Another piece of responsibility is looking up the appropriate conversion object given a temperature scale to convert from and a temperature scale to convert to. Therefore, as we have isolated a responsibility we should have a class that corresponds to this responsibility. That is the point of the class `TemperatureConverterFactory`: given a temperature scale to convert from and a temperature scale to convert to it will produce the appropriate `ITemperatureConverter`.

> What does inheriting the interface of ITemperatureConverter let me do? Does it allow me to use some built-in functions of Temperature Conversion in .NET?

We don't talk of inheriting interfaces, we talk of implementing them. An interface is a contract and a class that implements an interface is a class whose instances obey the contract. Think of a class (e.g., `FahrenheitToCelciusConverter`) that implements the interface `ITemperatureConverter` as saying "I know how to convert temperatures."

As far as I know, there aren't any built-in temperature conversion routines in the .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but could you explain this a little more from a n00by perspective?  I'm having some trouble interpreting your second block of code.

Comment: What does inheriting the interface of `ITemperatureConverter` let me do?  Does it allow me to use some built-in functions of Temperature Conversion in .NET?

Comment: @BOSS: I responded to your questions; let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Yeah, ok, that helps a little, thanks for the clarification.  Now, are your two original code blocks mutually exclusive?  Do they belong in the same program?

Comment: @BOSS: If I were making an app to convert temperatures, I would have the executable in one assembly and the definition of `ITemperatureConverter` and concrete implementations of it in another assembly.

Comment: The OO analysis in this answer is good, but I wouldn't advocate a system that grows in complexity in this fashion (`n^2 - n` classes).

Answer (score 3):

I would simply convert any input to e.g. Celsius. Then back to the scale you desire.

Comment: Yes, have all classes deal in a common input or output value (based on which direction you're going).  And then chain them.

Comment: That's a way to implement it, but it doesn't offer much on the design which is clearly what the OP is struggling with.

Comment: I'd use the SI unit for temperature, Kelvin as internal scale. One of it's advantages(that is shares with Rankine) is that it's 0 is at absolute 0, so if you do temperature math it will be the most convenient choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TemperatureConverter
{
  private readonly double TempAtZero;
  private readonly double StepSize;

  public TemperatureConverter(double tempAtZero,double stepSize)
  {
    TempAtZero=tempAtZero;
    StepSize=stepSize;
  }

  public double ToKelvin(double temp)
  {
    return (temp-TempAtZero)/StepSize;
  }
  public double FromKelvin(double tempInKelvin);
  {
    return TempAtZero+StepSize*tempInKelvin;
  }

  public static double Convert(double temperature,TemperatureConverter sourceScale,TemperatureConverter targetScale)
  {
    return targetScale.FromKelvin( sourceScale.ToKelvin(temperature));
  }

  public static readonly Kelvin=new TemperatureConverter(0,1);
  public static readonly Celsius=new TemperatureConverter(-272.15, 1);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
double celsius = TemperatureConverter.Celsius.FromKelvin(300);
double celsius2 = TemperatureConverter.Celsius.FromKelvin( TemperatureConverter.Fahrenheit.ToKelvin(100));
double celsius3 = TemperatureConverter.Convert(100,TemperatureConverter.Fahrenheit,TemperatureConverter.Celsius);//using the helpermethod
```

The limitation of this design is that it only works for temperature scales between which the transformation is linear. If it isn't linear you need to make `ToKelvin` / `FromCelvin` virtual or abstract or use an interface.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a temperature converter and I relied heavily on delegates.

Create one delegate that can represents a conversion formula, i.e.

```
public delegate double ConversionFormula(double temperature);
```

The shape of this delegate dictates that it takes a double, i.e a temperature and returns a double which will be the converted value.

Note that a delegate is equivalent to a class implementing a one method interface.

Define some methods with the formulas to convert.  you can create a normal method, use anonymous functions or I found it more concise to use Lambda expressions.  Of course if you are not up on these, you might need to do a bit of research.  Example conversion formulas:-

```
public static ConversionFormula FahrenheitToCelcius = t => ((t - 32) * 5/9);   
public static ConversionFormula FahrenheitToKelvin = t => ((t -32) / 1.8) + 273.15
```

Next I created a class called TemperatureConverter which has the following method:-

```
public static double ConvertTemperature(double temperatureValue, ConversionFormula formula)
{           
    return conversionFormula(temperatureValue);
}
```

I then pass in the temperature to convert along with the appropriate conversion delegate and hey presto, you get the result you need.